# Why are all snap processes hanging?

Tags: fedora, snap, qubes

Chromium, which I installed using snap, started hanging on startup. `snap list` hangs. `snap changes` hangs. `snap version` hangs. All the troubleshooting steps [here](https://snapcraft.io/docs/troubleshooting#heading--connection) result in either a hang, or an error, or no change in the situation. This is in a Fedora 32 VM on Qubes OS. The VM also hangs on shutdown, and has to be killed. A look at the console shows that it is hanging due to snap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the virtual disk which contained my home directory (`/rw`) was full.
Visible through `vgs` or `lvs`.

Increasing the private storage size for the VM immediately fixed all these problems.